# How to load pdf from java to object in html

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I develop a mobile app hybrid and i want to preview a pdf file that i get from web service.

The problem is the connection to the web service i do from java class and i want to preview the PDF in html.

I search in google and this i have until now and this not work for me.

Here my code:

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private boolean wantExit;
private ActionsApp doActions;
private WebView view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    doActions = new ActionsApp();
    view = new WebView(this);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    view.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/js/index.js", "javascript", "application/javascript", "UTF-8", null);
    view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.html");
    view.addJavascriptInterface(doActions, "action");
    setContentView(view);
}
}
```

ActionsApp Class: this class used for action to the web service

```
public class ActionsApp {   
public ActionsApp(){}

@JavascriptInterface
public String getFile(String idObjStr) {
    ObjectVersion objectVer = null;
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    JSONParser jsonParser;
int idObj;
InputStream fileStream;
try {
  fileStream = get from web service the file as Stream: application/png
      jsonParser = new JSONParser();
      jsonObject = (JSONObject)jsonParser.parse(new InputStreamReader(fileStream, "UTF-8"))
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonObject.toString();
}
}
```

index.js: when i click on button in another page(not the page that i wrote down here) the start this function in the js file.

```
function openFile(objectID)
{
$.mobile.changePage( "#pdfFile" );
var container = $('#previewContainer');
var pdfObject = $('#pdfObject').remove();
// The "format=pdf" parameter instructs the server to create a pdf preview 
of the file and return it.
pdfObject.attr('type', 'application/pdf')
         .attr('data', JSON.parse(window.action.getFile(objectID)));
        container.append(pdfObject);
  }
```

index.html: this page is to perview to pdf file that i get from the function in js file through ActionsApp class.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-
1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pdfFile" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <h2>pdf</h2>
</div>
<div data-role="content" class="ui-content">
    <div id="previewContainer">
        <!-- Embed a pdf previewer using an <object> element. This element 
  is modified in JavaScript. -->
        <object id="pdfObject" width="100%" height="100%">
        </object>
    </div>
</div>
 </div>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
   href="file:///android_asset/css/index.css">
    <script src="file:///android_asset/js/index.js"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Tal

Comment: This isn't an Android Studio issue, don't use that tag